# Diferencia entre @$request y $request

Tags: php

Hola amigos estoy usando Laravel 5.6 y trabajando en un proyecto ya iniciado, pero me toca refactorizar código y me encuentro con la siguiente sentencia:

Dentro de un controlador:

```
public function nombre_metodo(Request $request)
{
...
if (@$request->lo_que_sea)
...
```

La pregunta en concreto es: Por qué se utiliza el signo de `@` antes de la variable `$request`?
Yo con anterioridad lo he usado pero sin el símbolo de `@` quedando de la siguiente forma

```
if ($request->lo_que_sea)
```

Hay algún tipo de diferencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El usar @ antes de, lo que hace es evita los posibles mensajes de error que pueda tener esa expresión, tomando como ejemplo el tuyo:

```
public function nombre_metodo(Request $request)
{
...
if (@$request->lo_que_sea)
...
```

Que pasaria si `$request->lo_que_sea` tuviese errores o simplemente no llega, lo que haria seria mandar un error que `$request->lo_que_sea` no existe, para eso utiliza el `@$request->lo_que_sea` para evitar los mensajes de error.

Recomendación, para esto yo utilizo el helper `isset`

**EDIT**

Te dejo el enlace de la documentación.

> https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php